# Bulk insert from text file. SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert these lines from a textfile [image: lines] into a table using bulk insert.
Anyone who can help me what query will I execute in SQL server using bulk insert?

Comment: I think you'll have to format your data first. See some example here http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file

Comment: The _file_ itself has a lot of things. Here's an idea for u if you are coding with .NET language: Parse the file and pick the required _string items_. Now construct a `DataTable` with the same `Schema` of your `SQL Table`. Fill the parsed items into this `Datatable` and do the bulk insert.

Comment: doru chiulan is correct. You will need to format these into 'Insert' statements. Then check out SQLCMD to bulk upload.